# Google Maps API markers and zoom

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm relativ new to the Google Maps API.

My situation: Website with an fullscreen Google map as background.

First problem: If the user scrolls down, or zooms out too much, there is an gray background. Is it possible to limit the max zoom-out, and that he can't scroll out? Or maybe repeat the map vertical (with markers).
If it's possible to set the max zoom-out and lock him within the map, how could I dynamically calculate the max zoom-out releated to the screen-resolution?

Second problem: Is it possible to add custom javascript to a marker?
Example: I create 5 markers, each one should hold an custom value (ID from the database). On click my own function should be called with the custom value as parameter and do some stuff.

Edit: This is what I mean with grey: (vertical "end" of google maps)
[image: Vertical end from google maps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Got it finally working! :)

Fixing grey area (handles also zooming):

```
function setBounds() {
    google_allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.000, -122.591),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85.000, -122.333));
    google_lastCenter = google_map.getCenter();
    google_lastZoom = google_map.getZoom();
    google.maps.event.addListener(google_map, "bounds_changed", function () {
        checkBounds();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(google_map, 'center_changed', function () {
        checkBounds();
    });
}

function checkBounds() {
    if (google_allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat() > google_map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat()) {
        if(google_allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat() < google_map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat()) {
            google_lastCenter = google_map.getCenter();
            google_lastZoom = google_map.getZoom();
            return true;
        }
    }
    google_map.panTo(google_lastCenter);
    google_map.setZoom(google_lastZoom);
    return false;
}
```

Marker click handler:

```
google_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerHandler);

function markerHandler(event) {
    window.console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) object have propert maxZoom, set it when map created
2. yes it is possible, you can add click events, change popups open, and since it is javascript you can add any additional data just as simple as `markr.MyData = 'something interesting'`

I am not sure what gray part you mean? I can't see gray parts with max and min zoom in google maps

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Got it almost working. Do you may know a way to prevent scrolling out map (into the gray area)? And maybe a way to calculate a way for the minZoom based on the screen resolution? :)

Comment: could you please show what gray part you mean? because I don't see any